# Remove common elements between two list with repeated elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I need your help because I'm a bit stuck with this issue.

I've got two list with repeated elements:

```
L = [1,2,5,2,4,1,9]
S =[4,2,9,1]
```

I want to get the "difference" between the two list, as if I do `LS = L-S`, and the result should be `LS = [1,2,5]`.
I know that `l2` will always be a subset of `L`, thus `S` will never have a value not present in `L`.

Note that only one `1` and one `2` has been removed from `L`, because there was only one `1` and one `2` in `S`. `L` can have elements repeated `n` times, not just 2 times.

Do you know if there's an "easy" way to do this? I wouldn't like to get an `O(n^2)` program.

Thank you so much!

Comment: What if element is present in S but not in L

Answer (score 4):

Use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (Python's version of a [multi-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset))

```
from collections import Counter

L = [1, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 9]
S = [4, 2, 9, 1]

LS = list((Counter(L) - Counter(S)).elements())
print(LS)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 5]
```

The overall complexity of this approach is `O(n)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect, because I only came up with the idea of the for loop and removing elements, which is quadratic. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help @Ale

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
l = [1, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 9]
s = [4, 2, 9, 1]
for i in range(len(l)-1,-1,-1):
    if l[i] in s:
        s.remove(l[i])
        l.pop(i)
print(l)
```

But i have no idea about its complexity.

Comment: It's `O(n²)` because popping arbitrary item requires to move remaining items of that list.